# How to batch convert files from command line?

Tags: windows, batch

I'm converting music from a proprietary format that the Nintendo 3DS uses to wav. The only program that can convert this proprietary format is a command line program that takes input like this:

```
convert.exe -o converted music.wav inputfile.differentformat
```

I want to know how I can run this program for all files in a folder and keep the original file names. For example if I had 3 files called **music1.differentformat, music2.differentformat** and **music3.differentformat** it would run the command line program called **convert.exe** and generate 3 wav files called **music1.wav,music2.wav,music3.wav**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try PowerShell for this, instead of batch. The nice thing about PowerShell is that it retains access to regular command-line utilities, while also allowing you to leverage the more advanced scripting functions and commands that come with PowerShell.

Given your original post, I'm guessing the command syntax for your convert utility is something like this.

```
convert.exe -o converted [output filename] [input filename]
```

If this syntax is incorrect, you'll need to adjust the below script accordingly.

**Script Template**

```
$MusicFolder = '[Full path to music folder]'
$InputFormat = '[Extension for input files]'
$OutputFormat = '[Extension for output files]'
Get-ChildItem "$MusicFolder\*.$InputFormat" |
ForEach-Object {
    $Filename = $_.BaseName
    $InputPath = "`"$MusicFolder\$Filename.$InputFormat`""
    $OutputPath = "`"$MusicFolder\$Filename.$OutputFormat`""
    Invoke-Expression "convert.exe -o converted $OutputPath $InputPath"
}
```

***I haven't tested much of the above***, primarily because I don't really know what utility you're using in the first place, but it should work in principle. Here's the general breakdown of the commands and flow:

**Basic Concepts**

- Anything of the format `$[Name] = [Stuff]` is a variable assignment.
- `Get-ChildItem` is PowerShell's equivalent to `dir`. A key difference though, as with most PowerShell commands is that `dir` simply returns strings for console output whereas `Get-ChildItem` actually returns objects which have methods and properties that can be used when the objects are piped to other commands.
- The pipe character (`|`} redirects output from one command into another command for further processing, instead of simply displaying the results at the console.
- `ForEach-Object` takes objects in an array and runs a series of commands against each of them.
- `$_` is a built-in variable PowerShell uses to refer to the current object being processed in a loop.
- `$[Name].[Something]` refers to a property or method of a variable - remember, PowerShell works primarily with objects as opposed to simple strings.
- `'[Words and Stuff]'` represents a basic, static string.
- `"[Words and Stuff]"` also represents a string. However, double-quotes are special because they tell PowerShell to expand variables that are within them.

  - `$x = 'world'; Write-Output "Hello $x"` will output `Hello world`.
  - `$x = 'world'; Write-Output 'Hello $x'` will output `Hello $x`.
- The grave accent (`` ` ``) is an escape character, which tells PowerShell to include the following character in a string as-is instead of processing it as a special character if it would otherwise have functional meaning in PowerShell syntax.
- `Invoke-Expression` is used to run commands stored as strings. This is useful for situations like yours, where we need to pre-assemble the arguments for an external command, and then execute that command with its arguments.

**Script Flow**

1. The first three lines set variables which we'll use later for constructing file paths.
2. The fourth line uses `Get-ChildItem` to take all files in `$MusicFolder`, with an extension matching `$InputFormat`, and forward them along the pipeline.
3. In the fifth line, `ForEach-Object` will take the files sent to it by `Get-ChildItem` and run the rest of the script block against each of them.
4. The next three lines are used to further build the file path details we'll need to provide proper arguments to `convert.exe`.

   - `BaseName` is a property of file objects that contains just the file name - excluding the folder structure and the file extension.
   - Note the escaped double-quotes in `$InputPath` and `$OutputPath`. This is so the actual string values will have double-quotes around them since a command-line utility like yours will most likely require them in order to properly process paths with spaces or other special characters in them.
5. The last line before the close-brace puts everything together and runs `convert.exe` with the proper arguments.

**Example Script**

```
$MusicFolder = 'C:\Users\Me\My Documents\Music'
$InputFormat = 'mp3'
$OutputFormat = 'wav'
Get-ChildItem "$MusicFolder\*.$InputFormat" |
ForEach-Object {
    $Filename = $_.BaseName
    $InputPath = "`"$MusicFolder\$Filename.$InputFormat`""
    $OutputPath = "`"$MusicFolder\$Filename.$OutputFormat`""
    Invoke-Expression "convert.exe -o converted $OutputPath $InputPath"
}
```